# List a comma-separated name without the comma

Tags: sql, select

In SQL+ I am supposed to make a table with one column:  name.  In that column there is only one name, 'Doe,John'.  I am supposed to write a select statement to show the data as 'John Doe';  I've looked, but I can't seem to find any way to do this.  Any ideas?

Comment: REPLACE() is the function you need but one column should hold one piece of data, it's always easier to concatenate data than split it apart. Consider splitting the column into firstname and surname

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?  Not sure how `replace` is going to help you here if you need to rearrange the data (lastname, firstname to firstname lastname).  And I echo others -- this really should be stored in two separate columns.

Comment: If the data is in an inconsistent format/order within the column then not even god can help him. Separate columns solves everything.

Comment: I know there are easier ways...but this is an assignment and I have to work with just one column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you should be storing this in 2 separate columns (firstname and lastname), let's assume that isn't an option.  The answer is going to be RDBMS specific.

For MySql, `substring_index` works well:

```
select substring_index(name,',',1) lastname,
   substring_index(name,',',-1) firstname
from yourtable
```

[Some Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a24a8/8)

SQL Server, you have several options.  Here's one using `substring` with `charindex`:

```
select substring(name,1,charindex(',',name)-1) lastname,
   ltrim(substring(name,charindex(',',name)+1, len(name))) firstname
from yourtable
```

[Some More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a24a8/1)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT REPLACE(name,',',' ');
```

Where name is the field name containing the data Doe,John.
So you are replacing the comma with a space character